# how to change the value of the array when the user types a new value in reached form

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

i am working on my recommendation system,it works fine but
when the user searches for a book ,it gives title and image of the books,but when the user type some other title with reloading the file i ,it gives the correct book title but it loads the  image of the pervious
searched book

here is my search route, which get book's title and its image

```
@app.route('/search',methods=['GET','POST'])
def search():

    choice = request.args.get('search')
    # removing all the characters except alphabets and numbers.
    # passing the choice to the recommend() function
    # passing the choice to the recommend() function
    books = recommend(choice)
    image=get_image()
    # if rocommendation is a string and not list then it is else part of the
    # recommend() function.
    if type(books) == type('string'):
        return render_template('read.html', book=books,image=image,s="oppps")
    else:
        return render_template('read.html', book=books,image=image)
```

here is my code to get the image, where i have defined img list gobally

```
 for i in indices.flatten():
            img.append(data[data.index == i]
                              ['Image'].values[0])
                                              
        return book_list
```

I can't understand why it gives the previous searched book's image,while it should display the current searched title image  (But it works fine when i rerun the py file again)

here is my searched form

```
{% block body %}
<form action="{{url_for('search')}}" , class="navbar-form" role="search" ,method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Books" class="search mb-3" name="search">
    <button class="search-btn">Search</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

can u pls help me out with this

**Thanks you in Advance**

Answer (score 0):

I think you got some logic error in your code, but from posted piece it is not clear what exactly is your issue.

For example, how did you connect that data: title of the book and it's image:

```
books = recommend(choice)    // here you get the book(s), based on **choice** variable
image=get_image()            // but what did you based on when picking the image(s) from the list
```

I think more code would clarify this problem.